# How do I get a file off google-api-java-client?

Tags: mercurial

OK i want download the the following open source code: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample/?repo=samples

I am lead to believe you need to use mercurial for this but have yet to find a tutorial on how.  Why is there not a download zip file type thing for this?

I am using eclipse.

How do I get this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get each file individually by clicking it then right-click "View raw file" in the right column and choose "Save" (which may say something slightly different depending on your browser.)

I don't know about this project, but usually you can download the samples in the zips on the [downloads tab](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/list)

If you want to do it faster than that, you can find a Mercurial client for most operating systems at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads.
Once you have Mercurial installed, running the command

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client.samples/ google-api-java-client-samples
```

will give you a full copy of the current version in the current directory.

Comment: ah thanks the current directory is why i couldn't find the file

Comment: Since Google Code closed, this question and answer are obsolete. The Google Java API has moved to https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client